# Devise is screwy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I put `require 'devise'` in application.rb, I get the error `cannot load such file -- devise` but when I take it out, I get the error `uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)` I can't win.

Comment: You don't need to add device to your application.rb. Have you added it to your Gemfile? Have you read the really thorough docs https://github.com/plataformatec/devise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my gem file was just completely messed up. I needed to restart my project.